# How to use section tag with angular js for make it responsive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, responsive

Can I use angular js with three sectioning of the web page for make it responsive by making two sections into dropdown buttons

```
<body>
    <section id="main">
    <section id="body">
        // data in li
    </section>

    <aside id="side">
        //data with links
    </aside>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML `section` tag has no built in behaviour, it just denotes a section of the document, normally with its own heading, where other tags such as `article` or `nav` are not appropriate e.g.

```
<section id="my-section">
    <h2>Heading for section</h2>
    <p>Some content</p>
</section>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section

> The HTML  element represents a standalone section of functionality contained within an HTML document, typically with a heading, which doesn't have a more specific semantic element to represent it.
>
> As an example, a navigation menu should be wrapped in a  element, but a list of search results and a map display and its controls don't have specific elements, and could be put inside a .

So for making a responsive layout, using `section` over `div` or any other element does not really have any meaning. You must use CSS (e.g. with media queries) or JavaScript to change the layout (FYI, the default for `section` is `display: block`).

Comment: going on bootstrap